# making a presence/absence timeline in r for multiple y objects

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my first time using SO and I am an R newbie; sorry if this is a little basic or unclear (or if the question has already been answered... I'm struggling with coding and need pretty specific answers to understand)

I would like to produce an image similar to this one:

[image: here]

Except I would like it to be oriented horizontally on a timeline, and with two vertical lines drawn from the x-axis.

I can set the data up simply, and there are only two variables - date and Tag.

```
    Tag Date
1   1   1/1/2014
2   3   1/1/2014
3   1   1/3/2014
4   2   1/3/2014
5   3   1/3/2014
6   5   1/3/2014
7   2   1/4/2015
8   3   1/4/2015
9   4   1/4/2015
10  6   1/4/2015
11  1   1/5/2014
12  2   1/5/2014
13  4   1/5/2014
14  6   1/5/2014
15  1   1/6/2014
16  2   1/6/2014
17  3   1/6/2014
18  4   1/6/2014
19  6   1/6/2014
20  2   1/7/2014
21  4   1/7/2014
22  1   1/8/2014
23  2   1/8/2014
24  6   1/8/2014
```

Here is a drawn image of what I would like to accomplish:

[image]

To recap -  I want to take this data, which shows the dates of detection of animals at a certain location and plot it on a timeline with two vertical lines on two dates.  If an animal (say, tag 2) was detected on consecutive days, I would like to connect those dates with a line, and if the detection happened without detection on consecutive days, a simple dot will suffice.  I imagine the y-axis is stacked with each individual Tag, and the x-axis is a date scale - for each date, if A tag ID was detected, then its corresponding x,y coordinate will be marked; if a tag was not detected on a certain date; the corresponding x,y coordinate will remain blank.

**Here's a follow-up question:**

I want to add a shaded background to some of the dates.  I figured that I can use this using `geom_rect`, but i keep getting the following error:
`Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

using the code you wrote, this is what I have added to receive the error:

`geom_rect(aes(xmin=16075, xmax=16078, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="red", alpha=0.25)`

this code will plot, but is not transparent, and so becomes fairly useless:
`geom_rect(xmin=16075, xmax=16078, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you provide the output of `dput(dat)` (where `dat` is your data?) that would make it easily reproducible.

Comment: What is the date format of your `Date` column? I thought is was `month/day/year`, but you have a few entries with `2015` as the year - are these supposed to be `1/4/2014` instead of `1/4/2015`?

Comment: The date format is month/day/year, and you are correct - the entries with 2015 as year are incorrect; they should be 2014.  I just made the data up to be exemplary of what I will use to create the graphic

Comment: `dput(dat)
structure(list(Tag = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1/1/2014", "1/3/2014", 
"1/4/2015", "1/5/2014", "1/6/2014", "1/7/2014", "1/8/2014"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Tag", 
"Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))`

Comment: `@nrussell`, `@DavidRobinson`  I think this is what you all may want - thanks a lot for the responses.  This thing is awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to change your date format into `Date`. Then you need to figure out if dates are consecutive. And finally you need to plot them. Below is a possible solution using the packages `dplyr` and `ggplot2`.

```
# needed packages
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
# input your data (changed to 2014 dates)
dat <- structure(list(Tag = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 6L), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1/1/2014", "1/3/2014", "1/4/2014", "1/5/2014", "1/6/2014", "1/7/2014", "1/8/2014"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Tag", "Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
# change date to Date format
dat[, "Date"] <- as.Date(dat[, "Date"], format='%m/%d/%Y')
# adding consecutive tag for first day of cons. measurements
dat <- dat %>% group_by(Tag) %>% mutate(consecutive=c(diff(Date), 2)==1)
# plotting command
ggplot(dat, aes(Date, Tag)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  geom_line(aes(alpha=consecutive, group=Tag)) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0, 1), breaks=c(FALSE, TRUE), guide='none')
```

[image]

Comment: Here's a follow-up question:

I want to add a shaded background to some of the dates.  I figured that I can use this using `geom_rect`, but i keep getting the following error:
`Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

using the code you wrote, this is what I have added to receive the error:

`geom_rect(aes(xmin=16075, xmax=16078, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf), fill="red", alpha=0.25)`



this code will plot, but is not transparent, and so becomes fairly useless:
`geom_rect(xmin=16075, xmax=16078, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)`

Comment: This works for me: `geom_rect(xmin=16075, xmax=16078, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, fill="red", alpha=0.005)`